# How to transfer items of one static list to another

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two static lists namely list1 and list2

```
private static IList<String> list1;
private static IList<String> list2;
list1 = new List<String>() { "v1001", "v1002", "v1003","v1004" };
```

I am trying to transfer items of list1 into list2

`list2 = list1`;

Now when i try to remove something from list2, that item gets removed from list1 also.

```
var version = "v1001"
list2.Remove(version);
```

How can i accomplish this, that i can only remove from list2 without hindering list1.

Comment: You know you are addressing the same list with two different variables, right? `clone` the list first.

Comment: Or create a second list and copy over the contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both list 2 and list 1 in your exmaple are the same object with variables list2 and list1 pointing at it. You can use

```
list2 = new List<string>(list1);
```

which will make them different objects.

Comment: is there a method called `clone()` which would work? pardon me, I don't know  C# that well

Comment: @Lobo not for a List.

Comment: @Lobo right a List<T> doesn't implement ICloneable, but you can just use the constructor overload I've pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the copy constructor:

```
list2 = new List<string>(list1);
```

or use Linq:

```
list2 = list1.Select(s => s).ToList();
```

which could also be called statically:

```
list2 = Enumerable<string>.ToList(list1);
```

NOTE: The other examples are only given for reference - the copy constructor provided in Yuriy's answer is the cleanest way.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that removing from list2 also removes from list1 is that both list1 and list2 are reference types. What I mean by this is that list1 and list2 basically store where your list is somewhere off in memory. When you set list2 to list1 with the = operator what you actually do is tell list2 "alright you're going to point to the same place in memory that list1 is pointing to." This means that if you change something using the reference list1 it will look like this change is duplicated for list2 (but it's actually just changing the same data). To get around this, instead of

```
list2 = list1;
```

I think you could use this (as Yuriy Faktorovich said):

Edit: try this

```
class Program
{
    private static IList<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "v1001", "v1002", "v1003", "v1004" };
    private static IList<string> list2 = new List<string>(list1);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        list1.Remove("v1001");
        print(list1);
        print(list2);
    }

    private static void print(IList<string> list)
    {
        foreach (string str in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeahhh its the same thing which @Yuriy Faktorovich said.

Comment: Yeah that was my bad. IList doesn't actually have a Clone() method (array does though). Watch out while using IList's copy constructor because it may not make a deep copy of a list of objects (it probably will though if you create a copy constructor for the object type in the list!).